# Ubuntu GeForce 550 no sound over HDMI

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-11.04

I have an Asus motherboard with a GeForce 550 Ti, connected to a TV over HDMI. The problem is I can't get any sound out of the TV from the computer. However, the command:

```
aplay -D plughw:NVidia,7 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

Does produce output, the sound comes through the TV fine. I have the latest version of the driver from NVidia installed, and the graphics card shows up fine in system preferences. Any ideas?

Edit: I don't get any sound with OS X Lion (Hackintosh) either, but I can get sound out of both OS's through the built in headphone port.

Comment: Year of Linux on the desktop, I say.

Comment: Check your PulseAudio settings. There was a tool to do that (to configure your output, etc), but it's been a long time since I've worked with Linux. (E.g.: Fight daily to listen to music, read my email, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or very similar problem: When plugging in my HDMI cable to my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, the screen mirrored to the second display (Sony TV), but the sound continued to play through my laptop instead of the TV. I found that I had to switch the Output device *manually* in Sound settings to the HDMI port.

[image: Screenshot: Sound settings]

However, **before unplugging the HDMI cable**, you must select your default audio device again manually, otherwise you will have no sound even if you reboot your computer. (This is a bug.)

I understand that the best solution would be a way for Ubuntu to detect the HDMI connection and automatically switch the sound output device, but I couldn't find  a way to do that. Maybe this answer will help someone anyway.